How do I make sure two entities manipulating the same SPI line with different linux modules don't collide, or is this handled by the kernel already?
TL;DR
I am developing some code for my SPI display that also has an SD card reader on it for use on a Linux board. I'm trying to use mmc_spi with the SD card reader portion, concurrently with a program that uses spidev to manipulate the display. I'm wondering if anyone could help me find out the answers to the following:

Does the linux kernel already takes care of the context switching & mutual exclusion between the mmc_spi driver and my code that leverages spidev both wanting to use the SPI lines, and probably with different settings.
If not, is there a way for me to easily implement this from the user space?
If not, is it going to be a fools errand for me to try to go into the mmc_spi drivers and make it respect a mutex in the user space?

Thanks in advance!
Setup
Hardware

Computer: Arduino Portenta X8 - a recent SoC with little community support (probably for good reason)
Display/SD: Adafruit ILI9341 TFT LCD - a 2.8" LCD display (connected with an 18-pin FPC connector)

I have these two connected with the Portenta's breakout board and a breakout for the display. I plan to print a PCB that the Portenta can mount on and the display's FPC can clip into. For reasons beyond my control, I absolutely have to use this hardware setup.
Software
OS (built with Yocto Project)
Arduino provides a repository for their Yocto Project OS for the Portenta X8. I have learned a tiny bit about how that works and have built their "development" version of the project that doesn't have all the fancy (annoying for development) filesystem/OSTree features. I have also added mmc_spi, which was already there but disabled.
Device Tree Overlay Changes
I edited what they already had for overlays for spi for the user side. There are three, but the third is used by the Portenta internally for other usage. The SPI bus numbering between layers is not very consistent so please bear with me with that part. I disabled the first SPI (sort of) so that I could use its chip-select pin as a second chip select for the second SPI bus, since they all only had one chip-select. I have set the first chip select on the second SPI bus to be for the SD card, and the second to be for the display.
ov_carrier_breakout_spi0.dts
/**
 * Portenta-X8 dtb overlay file
 * Arduino 2021
 */

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "fsl,imx8mm-evk", "fsl,imx8mm";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&ecspi2>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            num-cs = <0>;
            cs-gpios = <>;
        };
    };
};

ov_carrier_breakout_spi1.dts
/**
 * Portenta-X8 dtb overlay file
 * Arduino 2021
 */

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "fsl,imx8mm-evk", "fsl,imx8mm";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&ecspi1>;
        __overlay__ {
            num-cs = <2>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            status = "okay";
            cs-gpios = 
                <&gpio5 9 0>,
                <&gpio5 13 0>;

            sdcard0: mmc@0 {
                compatible = "mmc-spi-slot";
                spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
                reg = <0>;
                status = "okay";
            };

            spidev1: spidev@1 {
                compatible = "rohm,dh2228fv";
                spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
                reg = <1>;
                status = "okay";
            };
        };
    };
};

Display Code
I am using Go for this since a lot of the Portenta's design is to get you to use Docker containers for most code, but I want to run code directly on the machine. Go is great for this for me since it supports cross-compilation very nicely. I'm using the periph.io/x/conn/v3/spi library for SPI, which I initialize with my spidev device living at /dev/spidev0.1.
Current State of Things
With the above set up, I am able to see my SD card show up as mmc3 (mmcblk3 & mmcblk3p1 in /dev/) and am able to mount/unmount/read/write it.
I am also able to use the code I've cooked up in Go to write to the display. I'm hoping this leverages spidev in a way that makes the kernel play nice with itself, since mmc_spi and spidev are part of it. This might be wishful thinking though.
For reasons also out of my control at the moment, I can't wire up the chip-detect line from the ILI9341 to the Portenta, so mmc_spi has to poll. This unfortunately adds a lot of spi communication at unpredictable times. So I am concerned that when I run the code for the display, even if I have mutual exclusion between my display code and whatever scripts/code I add for the SD card operations, that won't be enough since SPI transactions are being commenced by the mmc_spi at times, at least for polling.
I am getting some trouble with writing to the display, where sometimes it seems to either miss an SPI transaction or it gets shifted/scrambled a bit. I want to just blame it on the fact that this is a breadboard set up and that I could also add a bit more timing logic to my code, but I want to make sure that before I pull the trigger on ordering a PCB to be printed, that I can at least be sure I am capable of making sure that it's definitely not the SD card and the display both being operated at once because of OS stuff. Is this a concern I should have at all, or is the SPI bus arbitration a non-issue here? If so, is there anything I can do about it?
